# Do I need to release an UnsafeBufferPointer, or the UnsafePointer used at the buffer pointer's starting memory location?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

Consider [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35730103/2415822) on `NSData` which serializes an `NSData` object into a hex String:

> ```
> extension NSData {
>     func base16EncodedString(uppercase uppercase: Bool = false) -> String {
>         let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes), count: self.length)
>         let hexFormat = uppercase ? "X" : "x"
>         let formatString = "%02\(hexFormat)"
>         let bytesAsHexStrings = buffer.map {
>             String(format: formatString, $0)
>         }
>         return bytesAsHexStrings.joinWithSeparator("")
>     }
> }
> ```

If an `UnsafeBufferPointer` is a non-owning pointer, does that mean I don't need to (or am not able to) explicitly call destroy?  If I'm creating an `UnsafePointer` from the memory of the bytes of an `NSData` object, do I need to make sure to destroy that pointer after the buffer is copied?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/25605658/1187415: *"destroy() is only necessary if you have non-trivial content in the memory referred to by the pointer, such as a strong reference or a Swift struct or enum."* – In that sense, `UInt8` is "trivial content", and it is irrelevant if you call destroy or not.

Comment: @MartinR thanks.  So `UnsafePointer(self.bytes)` won't leak, since as soon as it falls out of scope it will be released?

Comment: `UnsafePointer(self.bytes)` is only a pointer conversion ("cast") from `UnsafePointer<Void>` to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`. It does not allocate memory. The memory is managed by the `NSData` object.

Comment: @MartinR Ah of course, because we're not calling alloc.  Thanks.  If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UnsafePointer(self.bytes)` is only a pointer conversion  from `UnsafePointer<Void>` to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` (like a "cast" in C). It does not allocate memory.

The memory is managed by the `NSData` object. You did not `alloc()` the
memory and therefore must not call `dealloc()` on the pointer.
You also did not `initialize()` the memory and therefore must not
`destroy()` it.